tfjs_binding.node is not available in node module when trying to use tensoflow.js in node
Solved: After running
    node-gyp configure --verbose

I've noticed message about outdated of Visual Studio C++. After updating, I finally had a different error, code related at least. That means, that installation is finally complete.
Original issue:
System information Windows 11 23H2
First it wasn't installing at all so I did like the other issue suggested the following:
     npm install -g node-gyp
     npm install --save-exact @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.1.0

And installation completed. But I did not manage to get past the execution issue of missing file as described below
I tried solutions in this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4171 and any stack overflow questions I could find. For example this one: "tfjs_binding.node" not found in @tensorflow installed folder.
I'm new to field and it is my hobby.
Logs error description:
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programming\Picturefind\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:49 throw new Error("The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not " + ^ 
`Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programming\Picturefind\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-node\l
ib\napi-v7\tfjs_binding.node.
Please run command 'npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-addon-from-source' to rebuild the native addon module.
If you have problem with building the addon module, please check https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/WINDOWS_TROUBLESHOOTING.md or file an issue.
at Object. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programming\Picturefind\node_modules@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:49:11)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programming\Picturefind\index.js:1:12)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)`

Node.js v18.13.0
First thing I tried as suggested:
npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-addon-from-source
Then I tried to Google different solution, but to no avail. For example, solutions in this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4171 and any Stack Overflow questions I could find. For example this one: "tfjs_binding.node" not found in @tensorflow installed folder.
I expected program to run, but it is not. File is not in the folder.

The error you're seeing tfjs_binding.node is not found occurs because the module is missing from its expected location within the napi-v7  folder. To fix this, move tensorflow.dll to the napi-v7 folder, where tfjs_binding.node is located . Additionally, please verify that you have installed the correct version of Visual Studio Build Tools.
